# 同じ名前のclassがついているボタンから１つのボタンをクリックさせたい

Tags: python, selenium, chromedriver

## やりたいこと

pythonとseleniumを使用して、毎日入力している勤怠の登録を自動化したいと考えています。

## 何をどうしたいか

現在苦戦しているところが、日付の分出てきているボタンをクリックすることです。
ボタンの箇所のhtmlは、実際のソースとは違いますが、以下のような形で日付分出てきています。

```html
<table>
    <tbody>

    //1~5日のもの

    <td class="td_type1" width="0%" align="center">             
        <input type="button" class="btnInput" name="btnInput" value="入力" onclick="edit('6');">
    </td>

    //7~月末までのもの

    </tbody>
</table>
```

勤務した当日のものを入力するつもりですので、
btn = driver.find_elements_by_class_name("btnInput")ですべての要素を取得し、
day = datetime.date.today().dayで本日の日付のみを取得して、
btn[day].click()で指定してあげれば、うまくいくかと思ったのですが、うまくいきませんでした。

print(btn)で配列をコンソールに出してみたところ、空の配列が表示されました。
ボタンを指定するやり方が悪いのか、全くわからないので、ご教示いただきたく存じます。

## 追記

コメントを受けて、追記します。
コードは以下です。よろしくお願いいたします。

```
# coding:utf-8
from selenium import webdriver
import datetime


driver = webdriver.Chrome()

# ここに繋ぎたいサイトのURLを入力
driver.get('勤怠入力のサイトのURL')

# ユーザIDとパスワードを入力し、ログインボタンを押下、勤怠入力の画面に遷移する
userId = driver.find_element_by_name("ユーザID入力欄")
password = driver.find_element_by_name("パスワード入力欄")
loginButton = driver.find_element_by_class_name("ログインボタン")

userId.send_keys("ユーザID")
password.send_keys("パスワード")
loginButton.click()


#トップ画面から入力の画面へ直飛び
driver.get(
    '入力画面のURL')

# 今日の日付を取得し、本日の日付のボタンをクリックする
today = datetime.date.today().day
btn = driver.find_elements_by_name("btnInput")
```

Comment: 手元の環境(`Python3.9/Selenium 4.0.0/ChromeDriver 95.0.4638.17`)で試してみましたが、全ての要素を取得できています。`btn = driver.find_elements_by_class_name("btnInput")` を実行するまでのコードを質問文に追記してみて下さい。

Comment: 追記しました。よろしくお願いいたします。

Comment: `driver.get('入力画面のURL')` の直後に wait を入れてみてはどうでしょうか。`WebDriverWait(driver, 3).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CLASS_NAME, 'btnInput')))`    `WebDriverWait`などの import に関しては調べてみて下さい。